# Invertible jacket?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I am not a native speaker, and I am having trouble finding a correct name for a piece of clothing (such as a jacket or cloak) that can be inverted (turned "inside out") and still be used but would have a different look, color, etc.

"Upside-down jacket"? "Invertible jacket"? Anything else?

Comment: It's called *reversible*. Sometimes it's two solid colors, sometimes one solid and one pattern on the reverse. Inverting usually means upside down.

Comment: Exactly, @Yosef for example [this reversible jacket](http://m.shop.nordstrom.com/s/missani-le-collezioni-classic-fit-reversible-leather-lambswool-car-coat/3821328?origin=keywordsearch-personalizedsort&fashioncolor=VINTAGE%20WHITE%2FSAND%2FMAUVE) Note the details: "This classic zip-front lambskin leather car coat reverses to a button-front herringbone lambswool jacket for double the warmth and style. The leather side features on-seam pockets, while the wool side has dual entry flap pockets."

Comment: @Yosef and Clare, thanks! So, it will be "reversible jacket"...

Comment: It works for cloaks also. Search online for [reversible cloak](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reversible+cloak&atb=v245-1&iax=images&ia=images) -  or [reversible cape](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reversible+cape&atb=v245-1&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images)
 - Capes are generally shorter.

Comment: Upside-down has a different meaning, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term I'm familiar with is [*reversible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_garment). It's a term used with all types of clothing, even [socks](https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/adidas-mens-originals-reversible-crew-socks-16adimmrgrvrsblsnapa/16adimmrgrvrsblsnapa)!

Here are some examples of reversible jackets:

- [Men's Reversible Jackets](http://www.eddiebauer.com/view/men/jackets/features-reversible/)
- [Womens Reversible Coats & Jackets](https://www.kohls.com/catalog/womens-reversible-coats-jackets-outerwear-clothing.jsp?CN=Gender:Womens+Feature:Reversible+Product:Coats%20%26%20Jackets+Category:Outerwear+Department:Clothing)

Reversible or not, cloaks aren't really everyday clothing, so you'll mostly find results for costumes (but that's more about fashion than the English language).

Comment: Laurel, thanks! About cloak -- well, I didn't insist on *everyday*  clothing, but your explanation was helpful anyway.